# How to get relationships to show on dbvisualizer?

Tags: dbvisualizer

I have tables inside a schema inside a DB. I need dbvis to graph/show the actual lines that show the relationships among the PKs as in the link below.

https://www.dbvis.com/features/tour/references-graphs/

For some reason, I can only get dbvis to display the column name and type in the diagram, but no PKs or links show up. How can I get these to show on the graph/diagram?

Comment: What database are you using? Note also that the references graph requires primary/foreign keys between the tables to render relationships. Read more in: http://confluence.dbvis.com/display/UG92/Viewing+Entity+Relationships

Comment: Using postgres. Thanks. I think it is because PK - FK references are not set up among the tables.